# Растягивать div на всю страницу + учитывать контент

Tags: css, html

Пример обычного div, который растягивается на всю страницу: [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjRMjP)

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 32px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="content">
asdfa fasd fasd fasd fasd fsd fasd asdfa sdf asdfa sdf asdf asd sd asd sd fasd fasd fasd fasd f
  </span>
</div>
```

Все хорошо, пока контент не становится длиннее всей страницы. В таком случае контент не растягивает внешний div. Это решается при помощи `display: inline-block;` на внешнем div, но в таком случае он перестает растягиваться на всю страницу, если контента мало. Как это можно решить?

Нужно, что бы div занимал всю страницу, если контента мало, и растягивался в длину, если контент превышает длину страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
88px = margin-left(32px) + margin-right(32px) + padding-left(12px) + padding-right(12px)
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 32px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  min-width: calc(100% - 88px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="content">
    asdfa fasd fasd fasd fasd fsd fasd asdfa sdf asdfa sdf asdf asd sd asd sd fasd fasd fasd fasd f
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант мне подошел лучше других.

Answer (score 2):

...Пишу в ответ, т.к. не хватает репутации на комментирование....

У меня получилось вот так:

```css
body {
 display: flex;
}
.container {
 flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 32px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px 12px;
 }

.content {
 border: 1px solid red;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="content">
asdfa fasd fasd fasd fasd fsd fasd asdfa sdf asdfa sdf asdf asd sd asd sd fasd fasd fasd fasd fasda
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это работает. Мне вариант с `calc` подошел лучше, так как он шире поддерживается, чем `flex`.

Answer (score 1):

[`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) и [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) устанавливает минимальную и максимальную ширину блока соответственно.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 32px 10px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="content">
asdfa fasd
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="content">
asdfa fasd fasd fasd fasd fsd fasd asdfa sdf asdfa sdf asdf asd sd asd sd fasd fasd fasd fasd fasdad
  </span>
</div>
```